# How to have multiple Context selectors?

Tags: web-scraping, css-selectors

I'm currently working on a scraper,

alot of my current code looks like this

```
contextSelector = 'a[href^="/clubs-and-societies/academic/';
```

(this works)

However there are multiple pages to select, having multiple ContextSelectors does not work

```
contextSelector = 'a[href^="/clubs-and-societies/academic/'; 
    contextSelector = 'a[href^="/clubs-and-societies/culture/';
    contextSelector = 'a[href^="/clubs-and-societies/dance/';
```

(not working)

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Two Points:**

1) Your syntax is not well-formed. It should be:

```
contextSelector = 'a[href^="/clubs-and-societies/academic/"]';
```

(Note the closing double quote `"` and the closing square bracket `]`.)

2) The logical `OR` in CSS is a comma `,`:

```
contextSelector = 'a[href^="/clubs-and-societies/academic/"], a[href^="/clubs-and-societies/culture/"], a[href^="/clubs-and-societies/dance/"]';
```

Comment: Oh yes, thankyou I will correct the Syntax. Unfortunately Adding a  ' , '  doesn't work